# Adding a value to <List> from range of excel cells

Tags: c#, list, closedxml

The data is taken from Excel, using ClosedXML. The problem is that I have no idea how many values will be in the column. Maybe 5, maybe more. Therefore, I want ClosedXML to take into account all the filled cells in the range and add them to the list. Here's what my code looks like now: I take the values manually, from each cell.

```
var tasks = workbook.Worksheet(1);
Tasks = new List<Task>()
                        {
                            new Task()
                            {
                                TaskName = tasks.Cell("A2").GetFormattedString(),
                                TaskStart = tasks.Cell("B2").GetFormattedString(),
                                TaskEnd = tasks.Cell("C2").GetFormattedString(),
                                TaskStatus = tasks.Cell("D2").GetFormattedString()
                            },
                            new Task()
                            {
                                TaskName = tasks.Cell("A3").GetFormattedString(),
                                TaskStart = tasks.Cell("B3").GetFormattedString(),
                                TaskEnd = tasks.Cell("C3").GetFormattedString(),
                                TaskStatus = tasks.Cell("D3").GetFormattedString()
                            }}
```

Comment: Can I assume that columns A to D all have the same number of rows, i.e. that the data that you want to read is a table?

Comment: yeah, it is a table with the same number of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your cells if there is content in them and add a Tasks if true. Since columns are linear, increment a counter and use it as part of the cell-name.

```
var tasks = workbook.Worksheet(1);
var Tasks = new List<Task>();
int loopCount = 2; //your starting row

while(tasks.Cell("A" + loopCount).GetFormattedString().Length > 0)
{
    Tasks.Add(new Task()
    {
        TaskName = tasks.Cell("A" + loopCount).GetFormattedString(),
        TaskStart = tasks.Cell("B" + loopCount).GetFormattedString(),
        TaskEnd = tasks.Cell("C" + loopCount).GetFormattedString(),
        TaskStatus = tasks.Cell("D" + loopCount).GetFormattedString()
    }
    loopCount++;
}
```

I hope this is clear and helps you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use LINQ and iterate through the `ws.FirstCell().CurrentRegion.RowsUsed()` collection.

```
using (var wb = new XLWorkbook("test2.xlsx"))
{
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.First();

    var tasks = ws.FirstCell().CurrentRegion.RowsUsed()
        .Select(row => new Task()
        {
            TaskName = row.Cell(1).GetFormattedString(),
            TaskStart = row.Cell(2).GetFormattedString(),
            TaskEnd = row.Cell(3).GetFormattedString(),
            TaskStatus = row.Cell(4).GetFormattedString()
        })
        .ToList();
}
```